# Are there any other bug/issue trackers than TFS itself that integrates with TFS SCM?

Tags: svn, tfs, version-control, bug-tracking

We currently use BugZilla for bug/issue tracking, but are looking for other solutions which hopefully fits us better.

One of the features we really would like is integration with both SVN and TFS, as we use both internally (java folks use SVN, .NET folks use TFS), but I have yet to find any who does both. Many do integrate with SVN, but I haven't found any but TFS itself that integrates with TFS SCM. Are there any other at all?

EDIT: Thanks to both Martin and gregmac for your responses. I'll take this information with me in our further investigation in what to do.

(If I could, I would set both your answers as THE answer to my question, but gave that one to gregmac for having a little less rep than Martin and that SvnBridge might let us keep TFS source control ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try [SvnBridge](http://www.codeplex.com/SvnBridge),which makes your TFS server look like an SVN server. This would allow you to have Bugzilla or whatever point to multiple SVN servers - or if it doesn't support that, you could set the TFS svn repository up as an [svn:external](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html).

The otherside, I'd agree with Martin and say if you're looking to integrate everything together, then you should probably just integrate your repository as well, and get the .NET to use svn (since SVN is more portable than TFS). I'd highly recommend [VisualSVN](http://visualsvn.com) for this - it integrates very well with VisualStudio.

There is of course going to be a learning curve, because SVN / VisualSVN will be different from TFS.. but if you can overcome that, and having shared bug tracking across the company is a big enough win, you should come out ahead.

Comment: Cool. We will look further on SvnBridge for using both our SCM systems as a second alternative to Teamprise. The third alternative will be moving our .NET folks over to the open source stack as you guys mention. Most of us are already familiar with that too, so it is indeed a valid alternative

Answer (score 1):

This is going to look like shameless self promotion, but you might want to look at [Teamprise](http://www.teamprise.com) for hooking your Java guys into the TFS repository.  We have lots of happy customers who are doing just that.

Alternatively you could try using the [TFS Migration and Sync toolkit](http://www.codeplex.com/MigrationSyncToolkit) to link your SVN and Bugzilla repositories together with TFS, however it is non-trivial and I have yet to meet someone who has managed to do that satisfactorily.

In the interested of fairness I should also point out that you could also probably get the .NET folks to use the open source stack that the Java teams are using - however getting the integration working between the work item tracking, version control and build subsystems in that stack would be non-trivial and not likely to give them the experience they are used to.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yeah, I've already looked at Teamprise (noticed it after you replied to me on twitter about TFS and commenting WITs ;). This is one of the alternative routes we will investigate further.